# How to resolve this error: ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: android, eclipse

If this is the wrong place to ask this question, please direct me to a more appropriate location.

I am working on an Android project in Eclipse. When I attempt to view the Preference layout in graphical view, I keep getting this error:

```
ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

Here is my preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="General">
        <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Show default categories"
            android:defaultValue="true" android:key="default_categories" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Export">
        <EditTextPreference android:key="default_emailaddress"
            android:defaultValue="@string/pref_export_defaultemail"
            android:title="Email Address" android:summary="@string/pref_export_emailsummary" />
        <EditTextPreference android:key="filename_prefix"
            android:defaultValue="@string/pref_export_defaultfilename"
            android:title="Filename Prefix" android:summary="@string/pref_export_filenamesummary" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what its talking about, my searches with google have not come up with anything substantial.

Comment: The XML I posted is what its saying its from. When I try to view the graphical layout of this XML within Eclipse, it gives this error and doesn't show the layout.

Comment: Ummmm... preferences XMLs cannot be viewed in the Layout editor because ... they're not layouts. They just define a set of properties with which a ListView will be created in your `PreferenceActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your editing configuration to Android 3.0(if you're using 2.3.3 and below).

Answer (score 1):

Close Your Eclipse and Restart it Again...Usually Disappears

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. I changed the theme from "Project theme" to "Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" (my preferred theme) and it finally worked.